# Why does reticulate produce a FileNotFound error when sourcing a Python script?

Tags: python, r, reticulate

When I try to source a python script with reticulate, I get the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/Users/blah/blah/R/pyPYIN/src'

```
library(reticulate)

reticulate::source_python("R/pypYIN/src/pYINmain.py")
```

Yet, this file/directory really does exist as specified. I also tried using the full absolute URL and it does not work.

Any idea what is causing this error?

Comment: Does the path *mentioned in the error message* exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the python file (Here, abcd.py) in the same working directory as your r script and then use this:

```
library(reticulate)
source_python("abcd.py")
```